# Integrating with respect to -dx

Tags: integration

How is the following expression true

$$\int f(-x) \, d(-x) = \int f(x) \, d(x)$$

Now, if f(x) is an even function, then f(-x) = f(x). But how is d(-x) = d(x).

Is it because d(x) symbolizes a small change in x, and hence is not really the deciding factor? Because a small change in x is the same as a small change in -x?

Comment: You probably mean even function and not even number?

Comment: $f$ being even has nothing to do with it. Make the substitution $u = -x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a substitution.

Try putting $u=-x$. Then $du=-dx$, and also $d(-x)=-dx$, so everything works out.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: And then by the rule of differentiation you can replace u by x.